# Add to cart in redux-toolkit (state undefined), Someone, please help me?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add a product to the cart.

I don't understand why the state is undefined,

I have a localStorage 'cart' :

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {product: {…}, quantity: 1}

1: {product: {…}, quantity: 2}

console.log(action.payload): 
  {product: {…}, quantity: 1}
```

When I clicked the add cart button, my localStorage added correctly but the state was automatically lost

My code cartSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {
  createCart,
  getCart,
  updateCart,
  deleteCart
} from './../asyncActions/cart.asyncAction';
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    cart: data ? data : [],
    searchValue: '',
  },
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers: {
    //* get cart
    [getCart.pending]: (state, action) => {
    },
    [getCart.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload) {
        state.cart = action.payload;
      }
    },
    [getCart.rejected]: (state, action) => {
    },

    // create
    [createCart.pending]: (state, action) => {
    },
    [createCart.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload) {
        let idProductAction = action.payload.product.id;
        var index = state.cart ? state.cart.map((item) => item.product.id).indexOf(idProductAction) : -1;
        if(index !== -1){
            state.cart[index].quantity += action.payload.quantity;
        } else {
            state.cart = [action.payload, ...state.cart];
        }
        state.cart = localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart));
      }
    },
    [createCart.rejected]: (state, action) => {
        console.log('sai');
    },

  }
});

const { actions, reducer } = cartSlice;

const { clearStateCart } = actions;

export { clearStateCart };

export default reducer;
```

My code component Cart.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getCart, createCart } from '../../store/asyncActions/cart.asyncAction';

function Cart(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cart);
    let productList = useSelector((state) => state.products.products);

    const addCart = (product) => {
      getDispatchCreateCart(product);
    }

    const getDispatchCreateCart = (product) => {
      dispatch (
          createCart({
              product: product,
              quantity: 1
          })
      )
    }

    const getDispatchProducts = () => {
      dispatch (
          getProducts()
      )
    }
    const getDispatchGetCart = () => {
      dispatch (
          getCart()
      )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getDispatchProducts();
      getDispatchGetCart();
    }, []);

    return (...);
}
export default Cart;
```

my redux devtools show:

- cart/createCart/pedding : state cart has data.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq6rw.jpg)
- cart/createCart/fulfilled : state cart undefined.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwWlZ.jpg)

I don't understand why the state is undefined,
Hope everybody help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not state.cart, It will be lost by localStorage typeof undefined:

```
state.cart = localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart));
```

Edit:

```
[createCart.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload) {
        let idProductAction = action.payload.product.id;
        var index = state.cart ? state.cart.map((item) => item.product.id).indexOf(idProductAction) : -1;
        if(index !== -1){
            state.cart[index].quantity += action.payload.quantity;
        } else {
            state.cart = [action.payload, ...state.cart];
        }
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart));
      }
    },
```